# CakePHP 2.x: Send $this->Session->data array to another view/controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Looking for the most efficient way to do the following:

### Details:

1 controller:

- Reports

2 views:

1. **create_report**
2. **view_report**

**create_report** has a form where information is collected that will be used in the **view_report** view. 
I know the data entered in the form is available within the **create_report** view via the **$this->session->data** element.

### Looking for Help on This:

What I need to do is send that same info ($this->session->data) from the **create_report** view to the **view_report** view (through the controller, I assume).

### What I have so far:

Just a link:

```
echo $this->Html->link('View Report', array('controller' => 'reports', 'action' => 'view_report'));
```

But this only takes the user to the **view_report** view. It doesn't send the info in **$this->session->data** to that view.

I am thinking it has something to do with the Js helper, but I wasn't able to find any posts dealing directly with this situation for CakePHP 2.x.

Comment: Do you need data validation from create_report?

Comment: I will add the data validation eventually. For now, just getting it all to work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bypass data processing by controller action create_report and send them directly to report view and do validation there if needed. Just alter form creation in create_report.ctp view.

```
$this->Form->create('Report', array('action' => 'view_report'));
```

Data will be submited directly to view_report action and available in $this->request->data

Comment: Thanks so much! This ended up being the solution I used. I'm not too familiar with Sessions data yet, so this was a bit easier for me to implement. I'm sure I'll learn about sessions soon enough, though... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have data stored in the session as you say, then you can access it directly from your view_report view, or any other view for that matter. To do this you can use the Session Helper.

```
$this->Session->read('whatever');
```

To use this approach, make sure you have the Session Helper loaded. More information on it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html).

Or you could pass your session data to the view by using $this->set in your controller as you would any other data.

If you want, for debugging sake, to see the contents of your current session, you can dump the session from your view ...

```
var_dump($this->Session);
```

Answer (score 0):

this way can be used as well, in this case you can send to any controller's any action

```
$this->Form->create('Report', array('url' => '/my_contoller/my_action'));
```